# Is is considered bad code practice to put code into __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Most of the __ init__.py of a project I work on (python 3.7) are empty but some have code in it.

I am in charge of refactoring.

Should I move the code out of the __ init__.pys as much as possible ?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not

Comment: That entirely depends on what the code does. Everything in Python is code. Unless `__init__.py` is completely empty, yes, it will contain code. And it's okay for it to contain code. Only *what kind of code* may be debatable and very much depends on the specific situation.